# Pushing data into chunks from server to mobile client

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reactive

I am developing a windows phone application. On the first screen user enters some unique  code and based on that code there are say 200 or more records on the server which I want to return to the client(windows phone app).

As all those records can't be sent in one go as there could be a timeout possibility, so I want to sent those records in a chunks.

So what could be the best way that server could continuously sent data to the client without further requests.

Currently I am  pulling first 10 records from server and then request again and so on.

There is a strong possibility that in later stages server have more data for that user, but I am not worrying about that at the moment, as I could make the requests periodically(I a hoping rx and signal r might have some solution to that, but not sure).

Comment: 200 records doesn't sound like much data (unless those records are very large). Are you sure you can't send them in one go? Or zip them into a file and send this? If I assume a 'normal' record with something like product data (title, long description, prices) that should be only bytes and near to nothing compared for example to sending images.

Comment: In real scenarios, records could be more than 200 and each record has some images with them and also object is big enough. But most importantly I want to find some way to achieve this in this way(multiple responses).

Comment: what's wrong with further requests from the client? it can first get the total count of records and then request a 'page' at a time until they're all returned.